# puppeteer consuming too much disk space with temporary files

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm having problems with the puppeter, I need to optimize its performance and also know how to get it to pay for the temp files.

the arguments I use are

```
 args: [
                    `--window-size=800,600`,
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                    '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
                    '--no-first-run',
                    '--no-zygote',
                    '--disable-gpu'
                ]
```

Would there be any way to optimize it and not make it consume a lot of space on my disk with temporary files?

I open it more than 1000x a day with the scraper I make.

there's no way to be in headles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disabling the cache should reduce most if not all of your temporary files. Add the following args, like so:

```
'--aggressive-cache-discard',
'--disable-cache',
'--disable-application-cache',
'--disable-offline-load-stale-cache',
'--disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache',
'--media-cache-size=0',
'--disk-cache-size=0',
```

Moreover, you may want to disable images and CSS (see [here](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-increase-web-scraping-speed-using-puppeteer/)) to further increase the speed and decrease temporary files and network throughput.

Also, there are [additional flags](https://gist.github.com/JoeyBurzynski/4538a716dc8597ddab0a5ef742ad0e90) that may be helpful for your use case:

```
'--disable-extensions',
'--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages',
'--disable-default-apps',
'--mute-audio',
'--no-default-browser-check',
'--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required',
'--disable-background-timer-throttling',
'--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
'--disable-notifications',
'--disable-background-networking',
'--disable-breakpad',
'--disable-component-update',
'--disable-domain-reliability',
'--disable-sync',
```

If you try all that and still find that it generates a lot of garbage, you may want to look into Dockerizing your scraper. I recommend [docker-slim](https://github.com/docker-slim/docker-slim) if you do go the Docker path, as it significantly reduces the size of Docker images without any negative side effects.

Comment: Thanks, I will test!

Just one more question, when I close a page and open another in the same broswer of the puppeteer, how do I get this new page to be totally clean without cookies from the previous page?

Because I'm using it to authenticate and when I open a new page it is already authenticated, I would like to open a new page without having to open a new broswer

Comment: So to delete cookies, do
`const cookies = await page.cookies();
cookies.forEach(page.deleteCookie);`
Deleting cookies should clean up your stuff and remove any prior authentication effects.

Comment: awesome, great to hear :)